# Resistor-only solution to split 19V 3A to 3.3/5V and 12V 2A with common ground?

Tags: resistors, voltage-divider

I need to quickly assemble a simple thing, a LED strip driver with ATTiny/Atmega. My powersource is (as always) a universal laptop brick (17-21V output @ up to 4A).

So AVR would be hooked into a number of ULN2003 to control overall drain (near 2A, 12V).

The problem is, it would take few days to deliver me anything better than a couple of resistors (have a lot of those here), so can make only a common-ground resistor divider.

Problems:

1. How to calculate the resistors to power both parts correctly?
2. (even worse) how to limit the current for ICs to about 500mA? Only resistors, remember. Maybe a bit of transistors/capacitors, but (almost? ideas?) nothing smarter.

   [image: two resistors form a resistor divider].

Comment: To restate the obvious, this is a bad idea. Can you control the output voltage of the laptop power supply (keep it at 17V)? Can you measure current and voltage? Are the LED strips JUST LEDs (and maybe a resistor)?

Answer (score 4):

This is a bad idea! In order to use a resistor divider, you need to have a good feel for how much current your devices use. Also, while you may have a lot of resistors, you will need high power resistors. Resistor-divider power supplies are **EXTREMELY** inefficient

For powering the microcontroller, we need to make sure that the voltage doesn't exceed the maximum rating, or else it will die. For ATMega parts that tolerate 5V, the maximum input voltage is 5.5V (5V +10%). Lets suppose that the current through R1 and R2 is 10mA. R1 will drop `(Vin-Vreg)` volts, and then using Ohm's law we can find the resistance of R1: `(21V - 5.5V)/(10mA) = 1.55 kOhm` . R2 will drop the voltage Vreg, so once again Ohm's law shows us `(5.5V)/(10mA) = 550 Ohm` .

How much current can this supply source before we start having funky issues? This is hard to tell for me because the AVR has such a range of operational voltages (5.5V to 2.7V). If we say that we shouldn't fall below 4.0V, then the maximum load current is equal to: `(Vin - Vreg_min)/(R1) - (Vreg_min/R2)` or `(21V - 4V)/(1.55kOhm) - (4V/550Ohm) = 3.7 mA` . R1 will dissipate the most power, and if you're using 1/4W resistors, you need to be careful here. The power dissipation of R1 will be most when the load is drawing the maximum current: `P = (Itot)^2*R1 =10.97mA^2 * 1.55kOhm = 187mW` . Increasing `Iquiescent` (decreasing R1 and R2) will increase your maximum current, at a major cost to power. Increasing the operating range will decrease the power, but may cause issues.

If you can identify the current for each leg that you are switching, you may be able to just add a series resistor with the light bar. For example, if one of the legs normally draws 100mA at 12V, then you could add a series resistor `(Vin - 12V) / (Iload) = 90 Ohms`
and things should just work out without providing a constant 12V.

**Note:** Use as low of a voltage on your power supply as possible. I'm not sure if this is adjustable, but if it is, use 17V instead of 21V.

Answer (score 1):

You can only use resistor dividers as a voltage source if you know the resistance of your load and it is constant.  If you are switching LEDs on and off, for example, the load is changing and so will your voltage.  But even if you had a constant load, trying to get 2A from a resistor divider seems crazy.  You'd need very large power resistors.

If you have transistors, perhaps you could rig together some simple transistor regulators.  These usually require zeners, but do you have diodes???  You could put a bunch in series to the get the required voltage drop to set the base voltage.  Still... your transistor will be getting HOT at 2A and a 7V drop.

Answer (score 1):

Resistor only?  Very bad idea.

If you're open to using transistors though, as you mention, you could use one with a resistor divider as a crude linear regulator.  A basic NPN emitter follower should work for a positive regulator, giving a voltage roughly equal to V<sub>B</sub> (the resistor divider) - V<sub>BE(sat)</sub> (characteristic of the transistor, usually 0.5 - 1 V)

Using a resistor divider as your voltage reference means it's obviously just a ratio of the input voltage, so ideally you'd use a Zener as a reference.

If you don't want to use Zeners, you could chain normal diodes.

If you don't want to use diodes, you can use transistors like diodes.

If you want to avoid that, you might be able to (severely abuse) the leakage current of capacitors (especially electrolytics) near their rating to provide a voltage reference.